# Selenium performance with .NET and Jenkins - How to profile and improve it?

Tags: asp.net, .net, selenium, nunit, jenkins

I have an ASP.NET website that I want to test with Selenium. I want to setup a Jenkins instance on a "staging" virtual machine, to run the tests automatically.

The problem is that the tests run very slowly - several times slower than on my development machine. A single, simple test can take more than 2-3 minutes.

I'd like to know if this is to be expected, if there are any obvious pitfalls for such a testing setup as mine, and if there's anything I can do to profile and improve the performance of the test suite.

#### Info:

Tests run on a 2.7GHz 2GB Ram virtual machine with Windows 7 64bit.
My dev machine is similar, but with a 32-bit Win installation.

The following is done by Jenkins:

- The website gets checked out from source control, and configured with a custom web.config. The main differences are that it's compiled in release mode and it connects to a database on a different machine(also a virtual machine, on the same server).
- IIS is monitoring the website's directory and automatically reloads changes.
- The following command is run (directories sanitized): nunit-console *Selenium-Project-Dir* /labels
- The tests are run on the Chrome webdriver.

The selenium project uses NUnit and WebRunner.
Driver instances are created once - before all tests, in a [SetUp] attribute inside a [SetUpFixture] class. They are deleted once, in the class's [TearDown] attribute.

A sample test looks like this:

```
[Test, Combinatorial]
public void AnExistingUserCanLogin(
    [ValueSource(typeof(Drivers), "Good")] 
    IWebDriver driver)
{
    // This function clicks on some buttons and fills in some forms.
    LoginUser(driver); 

    // Make sure the user is now logged in
    Assert.IsTrue(driver.ElementIsPresent(By.ClassName("imgUserAvatar")));
    Assert.IsTrue(driver.ElementIsPresent(By.CssSelector("a.my-profile")));
    Assert.IsTrue(driver.ElementIsPresent(By.CssSelector("a.logout")));
}
```

(The "Drivers" class contains lazily-instances webdriver instances of FF, IE, Chrome. You can guess what the "Good" static property of the class instances)

Comment: Have you checked memory usage on the virtual machine? 2GB feels like it might be a bit low. Also, how long do the tests take to run on your workstation?

Comment: The memory stays at about 1:11GB used. The tests run in less than 10 minutes on my machine (I haven't checked with a stopwatch, but it's in that area). They take 50 minutes on the dev machine.

Comment: You should run the test suite on your development machine connected to the database the Jenkins server is using. That will rule out issues with the database/database server.

Comment: No luck, it's fast on my machine and slow on the staging machine.

Comment: Could it be because one machine is 32-bit and one is 64-bit? Or because one is a virtual machine? I'm also not 100% sure where the selenium browser instances are actually visualized, so that might be a factor, too.

Comment: The 32 vs 64 bit doesn't seem like the issue to me. Have you tried running the tests manually on the server so that you can watch them (i.e. running them from the command line)? Sometimes doing that with the Task Manager open can help you see what's going on.

Comment: Running several tests manually on the same machine gives me a time of 646 seconds. Running the same command in Jenkins has a runtime of about 3000 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about Jenkins to be able to help any further. But it does appear that is where the problem is.

Comment: Just for shits and giggles, have you tried using selenium-server with Chrome instead of using the chromedriver?  Might be something related to Windows Service shenanigans...

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it is a VM should not be a problem, and RAM sounds like it is good. What OS is being run though?  Some of the Windows OS have significant speed differences between the different bit versions (because of demands on hardware).  This is especially noticeable in Vista but I have noticed a difference between Windows 7 and Server 2003.

I have found that there is a huge problem if the machine running the 64bit VM is a 32bit machine.  It often seems to work well for a while and then as it continues to run tests will slow down.  Which should be a duh but the main thing is that there may be too many VMs being run from the same place.  Other programs will be affected by this and that can help troubleshoot if your VMs are on a company farm.

The other factor that has made a significant difference is if you are running the tests against different browsers. IE8 and IE9 will take the same selenium command and run them at different speeds.  I don't know why this is, I just know that I have seen it. Make sure the staging machine has the current version of Chrome (or at least the same as your dev machine).

How the staging machine is networked to the database might be making a difference.  This seems like a very small chance but if there is firewall crap between the two VMs that can have significant impact on time.

The only other thing I can think of that might be changing the length of time is if there are other programs being executed on the on the staging machine at the same time.    Checking the CPU usage might helpful. Personally,  I have noticed that my VM uses a lot more of the CPU than my personal machine.  If this is the case the only solution I have found so far is to give the VM more processing power or to only run the test and nothing else.

Good luck!